# Scikit-learn text autoclassyfiation with two set of data in CSV files - empty results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm working on an autoclassification project with to separate csv files first train_data.csv and new_data.csv.

I'm using file paths from local network drive to classify to correct categories. Sentences are rather short so I decide to skip steaming and stopwords removal and just run classifier to predict categories. Have good results during the testing phase around 81% accuracy and now using real-life data.

My outcome should be CSV file with 3 columns File path, Predicted category and "nice to have" % accuracy for a particular value.

Here is my code, now its producing empty column where should be predicted values.

```
# coding: utf-8
# In[24]:
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv',encoding='latin1', dtype={'SourcePath': str}, )
# In[25]:
import numpy as np
numpy_array = data.as_matrix()
X_train = numpy_array[:, 0]
Y_train = numpy_array[:, 1]
# In[26]:
data.head()
# In[27]:
data_test = pd.read_csv('new_data.csv',encoding='latin1', dtype={'SourcePath': str}, )
data_test.DocumentType=data_test.DocumentType.astype(str)
# In[28]:
data_test.head()
# In[29]:
numpy_array = data_test.as_matrix()
X_test = numpy_array[:, 0]
Y_test = numpy_array[:, 1]
# In[30]:
print(X_test)
# In[31]:
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                         ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, max_iter=5, random_state=42))])

text_clf_svm = text_clf_svm.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicted_svm = text_clf_svm.predict(X_test)
np.mean(predicted_svm == Y_test)

pd.concat([pd.Series(X_test),pd.Series(Y_test)],axis=1)
data.to_csv('outpoot2.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 
I found a solution so second numpy array should look like this

```
numpy_array1 = df.as_matrix()
X_test = numpy_array1[:, 0]
Y_test = numpy_array1[:, 1]
```

and then to save the output

```
df_out = pd.concat([pd.Series(X_test),pd.Series(predicted_svm)],axis=1)
df_out.to_csv('outpoot.csv')
```

then it works like a charm